# DVD not playing on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

When you insert a disc into the Samsung disc drive writer on my Lenovo U330 it doesn't play, but rather displays the contents as files.

Comment: The Lenovo U330 comes with CyberLink Power2Go: "
    Power2Go’s advanced burning engine makes it a snap to burn CDs, DVDs and Blu-ray discs — even the latest 128GB BDXL discs. Duplicate CDs, unprotected DVDs and Blu-ray discs by burning 1:1 copies of your discs. Save a copy of a disc to your hard drive as a disc image and later burn the images back to disc."

Comment: I am not understanding at least half your post, but keep in mind, the issue with DVD player software isn't the software, its the licensing. Microsoft and Lenovo cannot give you a computer with teh ability to watch DVDs unless they buy the right to do so. Microsoft does not, and Lenovo appears to have outsourced it to Cyberlink. Just download VLC. it will probably play your disk fine.

Comment: To clarify your question: If you insert a CD with data or a program on it, the CD can be read? If you insert a DVD with data or a program on it, the DVD can be read? If you want to burn data on a CD, the data is burned onto the CD? But: If you insert a movie DVD it is not automatically played?

Comment: This question is liable to being put **on hold** because you haven't provided much adequate evidence to support your question.

Answer (score 2):

Windows dropped support for DVD playback in Windows 8.  Users simply were not using Windows software to play DVD movies and it costs Microsoft money to license the DVD playback software.  However, there are plenty of paid and free DVD viewing software for Windows.  Just Google search for them.